# How to send zip file to server using SSZIPArchive

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ssziparchive

I am using SSZIPArchive library for zip and unzip file. Using Photos framework i fetched all images from gallery and zip all images into document directory using SSZIPArchive. But how will i send that zip file to my own server.

Comment: Google NSURLSession, posting local file as a body

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SSZipArchive: you simply want to upload a file to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it i changed all images to NSData and then send to my server.